# What are the key assumptions of ordinal logistic regression and what tests to run on STATA about them?

Tags: ordered-logit

As the questions specifies, I am looking for the main assumptions of the ordinal logistic regression and what tests should I run in stata to make sure they are okay

Answer (score 0):

Don't run tests to determine adequacy of model fit.  Instead ask yourself (1) is the lack of fit consequential and (2) if I do anything about the lack of fit, do I make things better or do I make them worse?  For (1) there are various model performance measures (e.g., pseudo $R^2$) to use, and for (2) you can use AIC to tell you if a model that doesn't make the assumptions is likely to predict future observations better than one that makes the assumptions.  These approaches are described in detail [here](https://fharrell.com/post/impactpo) and in other resources given [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo).  The first link shows how the R `rms` package `impactpo` can be used to quantify the problem from various different angles.  In short, emphasize the impact of assumptions, not just testing assumptions.